# Android - After changing my Android compile target to 4.3 I get compile error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have this code which used to work fine

```
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
     .setContentTitle(title)
     .setContentText(message)
     .setContentIntent(intent)
     .setSmallIcon(icon)
     .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 1, 2)
     .setAutoCancel(true)
     .setSound(defaultSound)
     .build();
```

But now I updated my compile setting to compile with Android 4.3 and the .build() method seems to be not found. Would anyone know why this happened?

EDIT

And in the official documentation, the .build() method is right there:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: what was the previous version you had the project at? also I see a period at the end of the `setSound` line then another at the beginning of `build` that would cause an error or is that a typo?

Comment: @tyczj yeah that is a typo. But the error persists after fixing that typo. And before I compiled with Android 2.3.3 and tried to go back to it just now, but the error didn't go away

Comment: what does the error say on that line? did you do a clean of the project also?

Comment: @tyczj the error says "The method build() is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder" - but that line was always there before. And yeah, I cleaned the project many times :)

Comment: If you ctrl-space after the dot does build show up in the list of methods available?  (i.e. does the IDE know about build?)   Also what happens if you comment out (temporarily) all the intermediate calls and simply call build on the NC.Builder returned from new?

Comment: @DaleWilson when I commented out the intermediate calls, the system still didn't recognize .build() and it isn't in the suggested method list. But mind you, that code didn't change. I used that code for about 9 months already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you somehow rolled back to an old version of `android-support-v4.jar`, from back when it was `getNotification()` instead of `build()`. Make sure that you are on the latest `android-support-v4.jar`.

Comment: brilliant!! That fixed it. I was at a total loss. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have two consecutive dots before build.  Remove one of them.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. The problem still persists with just one dot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to fix your `project.properties`.

1. Right click --> "**Android Tools**" --> "**Add Support Library...**"
2. Right click --> "**Properties**" --> "**Java Build Path**" --> "**Libraries**" tab
3. Select "**Android Private Libraries**" then choose to "**Remove**" it
4. Right click --> "**Android Tools**" --> "**Fix Project Properties**"

Comment: thanks, I followed these steps (very easy to follow! thanks!) but when I do the #4 step, the system is unresponsive.

Comment: Actually it put back the private libraries references. But now I am getting different errors. Now the system does not recognize the references in the GCM.jar libraries

Answer (score 1):

Well, I pasted your code into my SDK 18 environment, and it seems ok to me **(but I may be wrong)**:

[image]

**If this is correct**, then the reason it worked for me is probably because I followed the section "Adding libraries with resources" in http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html .

That is, I have added the android-support-v7-appcompat as a library project in my workspace, I have referenced it in my project, and I have added it to the build path. (Of course, I have also added the latest v4-support-lib to my project, but I think you have already done this).